# Disable browser scroll to errored input

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

When I submit form and the form has errors, like empty required input, browser scrolls up to that input. I dont want that. I have custom scroll to errored inputs and browsers scroll interfere with mine. How to disable this?

btw I use react-hook-form

Answer (score 2):

When you create your form with the useForm hook you just need to set the `shouldFocusError` to false

e.g.

```
const { register } = useForm({
  // ... other settings
  shouldFocusError: false,
})
```

ref: https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform